# ValueError: Unknown optimizer: Custom>Adam| Adam Optimizer on Raspberry Pi (TensorFlow 2.5.0rc0)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am a learning machine learning and I want to apply it on a raspberry pi. I have RPi 4b running on:

```
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"  
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
with armv7l architecture
I have installed tensorflow and it's version is 2.5.0-rc0.
```

I am trying to load my model I trained in colab which uses Adam optimizer however I get this result whenever I try to load it:

```
ValueError: Unknown optimizer: Custom\>Adam. Please ensure this object is passed to the \`custom_objects\` argument. See <https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object> for details.
```

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import simpleaudio as sa

# Load the trained ML model
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
   model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/pi/Desktop/project/pineapplemodeltwoclassbs16e75.h5')
```

What could I do to resolve the error?

I have tried adding this:

```
# Define the custom Adam optimizer
class CustomAdam(Adam):
    pass
# Register the custom optimizer
tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects().update({'CustomAdam': CustomAdam})
# Load the trained ML model
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/pi/Desktop/project/pineapplemodeltwoclassbs16e75.h5', custom_objects={'CustomAdam': CustomAdam})
```

and still resulted in the same error.

I also tried this:

```
# Load the Adam optimizer from the tensorflow.keras.optimizers module
Adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam

# Load the trained ML model
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/pi/Desktop/project/pineapplemodeltwoclassbs16e75.h5', custom_objects={'Adam': Adam})
```

and still the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format):

> Keras saves models by inspecting their architectures. This technique saves everything:
>
> - The weight values
> - The model's architecture
> - The model's training configuration (what you pass to the .compile() method)
> - The optimizer and its state, if any (this enables you to restart training where you left off)
>
> Keras is not able to save the v1.x optimizers (from tf.compat.v1.train) since they aren't compatible with checkpoints. For v1.x optimizers, you need to re-compile the model after loading—losing the state of the optimizer.

Since Adam Optimizer is a v1.x optimizer, you might need to re-compile your model. If you're not using the loaded model for training, you don't need to re-compile it. Just set the parameter `compile=False` when calling `load_model`.

For example:
`load_model('file.h5', compile=False)`